# Image View to Full Screen - Zoom needed

Tags: swift, image, zooming, fullscreen, pinch

Good day, I´m writting this question because I’m trying to add a zoom (pinch gesture) on a full screen image. What i did is use some functions that i found here, but i never found the way to add a zoom gesture (pinch). Basically I´m having an image (@IBOutlet weak var fotografiaContactoGenerales: UIImageView!) inside my ViewController and I applied the below code:

On my View Controller inside viewDidLoad():

```
    // add TAP Recognizer
    let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewControllerGenerales.tapDetected))
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1 // you can change this value
    fotografiaContactoGenerales.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    fotografiaContactoGenerales.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)
```

Outside viewDidLoad()

```
@objc func tapDetected() {
    let imageView = fotografiaContactoGenerales!
    let newImageView = UIImageView(image: imageView.image)
    newImageView.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
    newImageView.backgroundColor = .white
    newImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    newImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    // Set Tap Recognizer
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissFullscreenImage))
    newImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    self.view.addSubview(newImageView)
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
}

@objc func dismissFullscreenImage(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
    sender.view?.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

At this moment my app can display a picture in full screen but i do not know how to apply a routine or some code to allow users to apply pinch zoom on the displayed image.

Would you please help me by adding to the above code to allow a zoom pinch gesture?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you try to use UIDocumentInteractonController? "https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentinteractioncontroller" this should give u all for free, as long the sdk supports it :)

Comment: Understood, but, do you think that zoom pinch could be applied on above routine ?

Answer (score 2):

Thank you , I want to share the solution about this issue , was very easy, just i added a new Gesture with pinch and below function :)

```
@objc func scaleImage(_ sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == .ended || sender.state == .changed {

        let currentScale = sender.view!.frame.size.width / sender.view!.bounds.size.width
        var newScale = currentScale*sender.scale

        if newScale < 1 {
            newScale = 1
        }
        if newScale > 7 {
            newScale = 7
        }

        let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: newScale, y: newScale)

        self.newImageView.transform = transform
        sender.scale = 1

    }
}
```

Another step i did is to move or create the UIIMAGE var outside the original fullscreen function and that helped me.

With this now i can zoom the image, but now my issue is to allow to move the image with the finger ojjojoj

Comment: I'm also looking into how to move the image zoomed in...

Answer (score 1):

I added this as a global outlet

```
var headerImageWithZoom = UIImageView()
```

and

```
lazy var headerImageView: UIImageView = {
    let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    iv.layer.masksToBounds = true
    iv.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapHeaderImageAction)))
    iv.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return iv
}()
```

These are the actions:

```
@objc func tapHeaderImageAction(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let imageView = sender.view as! UIImageView
    headerImageWithZoom = UIImageView(image: imageView.image)
    headerImageWithZoom.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
    headerImageWithZoom.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    headerImageWithZoom.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
    
    
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    scrollView.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
    scrollView.backgroundColor = .black
    scrollView.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 4
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
    scrollView.bounces = true
    scrollView.bouncesZoom = true
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = true
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true
    scrollView.delegate = self
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissFullscreenImage))
    scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    scrollView.addSubview(headerImageWithZoom)
    headerImageView.center = scrollView.center
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
}

@objc func dismissFullscreenImage(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
    sender.view?.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

and finally this is the delegate func:

```
extension PinnedViewViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return headerImageWithZoom
    }
}
```